# Can a Coordinator send and receive data in a mixed XBEE S2C AT/API network

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, xbee

I have created a network using one coordinator(API) and two other routers(AT).

The goal of this network is having my coordinator connected to my raspberry pi sending commands to remote xbees to take actions (switching relays). In the same time I want the coordinator to receive data from remote xbees that are attached to sensors.

Now, I'm able to make the coordinator send API frames commands to remote routers. However, I want it to receive data in the same time from other xbees in the network, which I'm struggling to implement.

Is it possible for an API coordinator to send/receive data simultaneously? if so, please give me suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  If the routers in AT mode have `ATDH` and `ATDL` set to 0 (pointing to the coordinator), they will relay any received serial data.  Since the coordinator is in API mode, that data comes through in an API frame.

AT and API mode and the baud rate of a unit only control how the XBee communicates locally over its serial port.  You can have devices use different baud rates and a mix of AT and API mode and they'll all communicate with each other.  It's common to have "dumb" nodes using XBee modules in AT mode (serial cable replacement scenario) and a central API mode coordinator that can multiplex the communications by processing the API frames to identify the source of the data.

So configure a router with `ATDH` and `ATDL` set to 0, and then send some serial data.  You should see an API frame come in to your Raspberry Pi.